# Creating an application with multiple databases

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design

Not 100% sure if this is the correct place to ask this question (if not, please point me in the right direction!!!)

But I am trying to create a web app and I am using keycloak for its login. That has its own db and I have it integrated with my Quarkus app. I have a `docker-compose` file created with it spins up and manually tested it where it works and seen the DB gets populated.

Now I am in a situation where I want to add more tables to the DB but my current one is for keycloak and it seems wrong to me to add more tables ontop of a DB just for keycloak.

What would be the best way to go about this where I can access user information from the keycloak db but then also have my own db for my own tables for the app.

I get this is still a high level db design phase, just unsure of the next steps and need help/advice to get over this hurdle.

**Docker compose**

```
services:
  # keycloak server
  keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak:13.0.1
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: password
      DB_VENDOR: postgres
      DB_ADDR: db
      DB_DATABASE: keycloak
      DB_USER: admin
      DB_PASSWORD: password
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "8180:8080"

  db:
    image: postgres:13.3-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_USER: admin
      POSTGRES_DB: keycloak
    volumes:
      - ./postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "sudo pg_isready -U postgres"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
```

**Keycloak DB on pgadmin**

[image: keycloak db on pgadmin]

On the screenshot you can see there is 92 tables on the db and these are all added from keycloak.

Again, I get this is high level and a design implementation, but I need advice on how to get over this and create another database/schema/tables on my app

Comment: If the data are not connected (that is, you don't use the authentication information in your application) create a second database in the same cluster for your application data.

Comment: So a user would login but I will be using RBAC (a big reason for using keycloak) so yes I will be needing the authentication data in my app to be able to find out if a user is an admin or user

Comment: Check if you can put that keycloak into a separate schema (other than `public`) and put your stuff into another schema (on the same database) as well. That way things stay somewhat isolated yet can be used together in queries.

Comment: Ok so look into the schemas then? Thanks I'll have a look into that

Comment: Yes, if you need the data in your application, use schemas in a single database.